# Get Facebook's iOS browser reading GA parameters (for discounts) or how do you give feedback to Facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook

We've noticed that Facebook's built-in iOS browser won't read Google Analytics parameters - we use GA's campaign parameter to offer discount codes to fans during checkout (on our website).

This works in every other browser except when fans try to get the discount via Facebook's app.

Does anyone know away around this or know where you can submit feedback to Facebook about their app - we're having a bit of trouble penetrating Facebook's wall of bureaucracy!

Comment: Are you sure this is something specific to Facebook and not a) you're not passing the parameters through in your URL, or b) the webviews on iOS (regardless of app) don't support whatever mechanism you're using?

Comment: If I view Facebook in iOS Safari and click the same link, everything works. If I do this Via the native iOS app, the link opens via Facebook's in-app browser and the promo code is not valid.